# Javascript form validation, how do I enable a button and check details (more details inside)

Tags: javascript, validation

Ok here is how my validation works

There are three text boxes. **name | email | message.**

**Onchange** of each of them runs a function that validates them and adds 1 to a counter.

functions are:  **`email(), name(), message().`**

I have another function called CheckBut, which checks to see whether each of the text boxes has been validated by making sure the counter ===3. it then enables the send button.

**WITHIN each function email, message, name i have** `{counter++, CheckBut()}`

**HERES THE PROBLEM**: *A user will enter the name right, and then click on the email field. This will then run the validation code for the name. They then enter the email and click on the message field, and this runs the validation code for the email field.*

When they enter the message they cant click on the button becuase its **disabled** AND **the function to validate the messgage field WONT run until they click somewhere else**. HOW can I solve this? I was thinking of BLUR() but I dont know how to run make it work within the confines of my form.

Comment: may be you can make text validation via mousemove? or validation via hover button. Seems to me possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you attach your listeners to `onKeyUp` instead of `onChange`.  This will get them to run before the user clicks out of the text fields, which ensures that the send button will be enabled before the user tries to click it.

However, by listening to `onKeyUp` your validation functions will be executed many times and your `counter` will probably grow larger than 3 before the user even leaves the name field.  To address this, I suggest you remove the `counter` variable and instead track the validity of each value using three separate boolean variables (e.g, `isNameValid`, `isEmailValid`, `isMessageValid`).  Each validation function would simply assign a `true` or `false` to its respective variable.  `CheckBut()` would then be changed to simply check that all three variables are true.

Answer (score 1):

You may use onkeypress event for check field changes, and setTimeout for run validation if field not changed in last 3-5 seconds. Looks like this.

```
<script>
    var validNameTimer = null;
    function nameValidWait() {
        if (validNameTimer != null) {
            clearTimeout(validNameTimer);
        }
        validNameTimer = setTimeout(nameValid, 4000);
    }
</script>

<input id="name" onkeypress="nameValidWait()" />
```

#### Fix

Replace onchage to onkeypress

Comment: Fix event from onchange to onkeypress, but onchange may be added too (user cane past text over context menu)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not disable the button. Instead, run all 3 validations on button click event and if validation fail display an error message (optionally) and stop the execution (return). Error message can be shown in HTML element, or you can use `alert(msg)` function. Hope this will help. Best rgds, AB